# Avoiding duplicates without Sets?

Tags: java, arrays

I am in a beginner Java class and I haven't gotten the chance to learn how to avoid duplicated values when storing values inside arrays.

```
String[] newAlphabet = new String[26];

for(int I = 0; I < newAlphabet.length; I++){

 int random = (65 + (int)(Math.random() * ((90 - 65) + 1));
 char ascii = (char)random;
 String letters = ascii + "";

if(letters != newAlphabet[0] && letters != newAlphabet[1] ... so on and so on until
                                                               newAlphabet[25])
     newAlphabet[I] = letters; 
}//end
```

So this is my pseudo code for part of my program and the point of it is to avoid having duplicated letters inside the array.

The problem that I am having is inside the if statement. Instead of typing `letters != newAlphabet[]` to 25, is there another way of doing it?

I have seen some of the forums in stackedoverflow that I should use `HashSet` but I have not learned that? I can ask my teacher if I am allowed but is there another way to avoid this problem?

I have been thinking of using for-each loop to search through all the elements in the array but I haven't thought out the plan long enough if it's valid.

Comment: you can add values into a Set and after that add them all into the array. duplicate values will not be added to the set. If you do not want to use Set/HashSet, you can of course make always a search in the array if it already contains a letter but that will require a lot of extra testing so for a big amount of words the runtime is slow

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a Set?

Comment: I haven't learned to use Set, I will ask my teacher when I do see her soon.

Comment: You have a couple options.  1 - loop through the array and do basically what you're doing now.  2 - insert the characters in sorted order so you can perform binary search to determine if a letter is already in the list.  As a bonus, if you use option 2, you'll already know the insertion point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are talking about a beginner Java class, I am assuming you are fairly new to programming. So, rather than just give you a library function that will do it for you, let's walk through the steps of how to do this with just the basic code so you can get a better idea of what is going on behind the scenes.

Firstly, for any repetitive action, think loops. You want to check, for each letter in your new alphabet, if the one you are about to add matches it. So...

```
boolean exists = false; //indicates whether we have found a match
for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) { //for each letter in the new alphabet
    //true if this one, or a previous one is a match
    exists = exists || letters == newAlphabet[i]; 
}
//if we don't have a match, add the new letter
if (!exists) newAlphabet[I] = letters;
```

Now, as you are building up your new alphabet as we go, we don't have a full 26 letters for most cases of running this code, so only check the parts of the new alphabet we have defined:

```
boolean exists = false; 
for (int j = 0; j < I; j++) { //note in this line we stop before the insertion point
    exists = exists || letters == newAlphabet[i]; 
}
if (!exists) newAlphabet[I] = letters;
```

Finally, we don't need to keep checking if we have already found a match, so we can change the loop to stop when we have found a match:

```
boolean exists = false;
int j = 0;
while (!exists && j < I) { //we now also stop if we have already found a match
    exists = letters == newAlphabet[i]; 
    //as we are stopping at the first match, 
    //we no longer need to allow for previous matches
}
if (!exists) newAlphabet[I] = letters;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `asList` method:

```
if( Arrays.asList(newAlphabet).contains(letters) ) {
    newAlphabet[I] = letters; 
}
```

It's not the most efficient, but since your array is only 26 elements long, I would favor clarity over efficiency.

Some explanation: `asList` is a static method on the `Arrays` class.  This just means that we don't have to create an `Arrays` object to call it.  We simply say `Arrays.asList()` and pass it the arguments.  The `asList` method takes an array (`newAlhpabet` in this case) as a parameter, and builds a `java.util.List` out of it.  This means that we can call `List` methods on the return value.  `contains()` is a method on `List` that returns true if the `List` contains an element that is equal to the parameter (`letters` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Based on this line it looks like all you're trying to do is produce the letters `A` to `Z` in some other order:

```
int random = (65 + (int)(Math.random() * ((90 - 65) + 1));
```

If I'm understanding that right, then really all you're trying to do is *shuffle* the alphabet:

```
// Initialize new alphabet array
String originalAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char[] newAlphabet = originalAlphabet.toCharArray();
// Shuffle the new alphabet by swapping each character to a random position
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
  int j = (int)(Math.random() * 26);
  char temp = newAlphabet[i];
  newAlphabet[i] = newAlphabet[j];
  newAlphabet[j] = temp;
}
// Print the new alphabet
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
  System.out.print(newAlphabet[i]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Here's a sample output: `VYMTBIPWHKZNGUCDLRAQFSOEJX`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.

1. Loop through the array and do basically what you're doing now.
2. Insert the characters in sorted order so you can perform binary search to determine if a letter is already in the list. As a bonus, if you use option 2, you'll already know the insertion point.

Check out Arrays.binarySearch(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Keeping the array sorted is going to involve a _lot_ of copying. I think the comment suggesting using a set and then converting it to an array would be more efficient and require less logic.

Comment: He specifically mentioned not wanting to use a Set.  Probably due to homework restrictions.  My answer reflects that.

Comment: That's true, but I think using `binarySearch` to manually maintain a sorted set in an array is way more complex and requires more than just a black-box understanding of sets, so if the teacher doesn't want them using sets then I doubt that doing it this way would be better. This is definitely worth mentioning as an alternative, but I don't think it's the best fit here.

Comment: Then he can feel free to use option 1.  :-)

Answer (score -3):

You could use this :

```
if(Arrays.binarySearch(newAlphabet, letters) < 0){
  newAlphabet[I] = letters;
 }
```

You should either include a `while` loop to make sure each index of the array is filled before moving to the next or you could make use of the return value of `Arrays.binarySearch` which is `(-(insertion index) - 1)` to fill the array and exit when the array is filled up.